# Calculating simple moving averages using rolling() function with time-based data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I have a following DataFrame:

```py
dates = ['2018-01-03 23:26:00', '2018-01-04 00:14:00', '2018-01-04 03:10:00', '2018-01-05 03:47:00',
'2018-01-05 04:47:00', '2018-01-06 05:44:00', '2018-01-06 19:00:00', '2018-01-06 20:36:00',
'2018-01-07 21:34:00']

vals = [59.95, 60.11, 62.05, 59.98, 60.01, 61.15, 60.35, 60.61, 59.99]

temp = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'values':vals})
```

What I need to do is get rolling averages for the past 24 hours. I tried using pandas' `rolling()` function, but there I can specify a window of how many data points to use for rolling calculations, I can have different number of data points for every 24-hour period, so simple use of the rolling function doesn't work for me.

I thought about resampling dataframe by date, by that wouldn't work either.

Not sure how to approach this. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: Why is this not working?
`temp= temp.set_index('date').sort_index()`
`temp.rolling('24H').mean()`
Are you using pandas <0.19?

Comment: @XXavier, nice! That works! For some reason I didn't find in the documentation that you can actually use time periods with `rolling()` function. Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the date as the index, then use the pandas rolling function with a set time period for the window.

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['2018-01-03 23:26:00', '2018-01-04 00:14:00', '2018-01-04 03:10:00', '2018-01-05 03:47:00',
'2018-01-05 04:47:00', '2018-01-06 05:44:00', '2018-01-06 19:00:00', '2018-01-06 20:36:00',
'2018-01-07 21:34:00']

vals = [59.95, 60.11, 62.05, 59.98, 60.01, 61.15, 60.35, 60.61, 59.99]

temp = pd.DataFrame({'values':vals})
temp.index = [pd.Timestamp(date) for date in dates]

# create a new column with rolling average values
temp['rolling_avg'] = temp.rolling('24h', min_periods=1).mean()
```

Output:

```
>>> temp
                     values  rolling_avg
2018-01-03 23:26:00   59.95    59.950000
2018-01-04 00:14:00   60.11    60.030000
2018-01-04 03:10:00   62.05    60.703333
2018-01-05 03:47:00   59.98    59.980000
2018-01-05 04:47:00   60.01    59.995000
2018-01-06 05:44:00   61.15    61.150000
2018-01-06 19:00:00   60.35    60.750000
2018-01-06 20:36:00   60.61    60.703333
2018-01-07 21:34:00   59.99    59.990000
```